# Stuck with an equation having 6 unknowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Suppose $a,b,c,d,e,f\in\mathbb{R}$ and satisfy the following equation:

$c^2d^2-2bcde+b^2e^2-2acdf+a^2f^2-2abef=0$

Show that the above equation cannot hold if all of the unknown quantities $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are nonzero.

I did the following: I rewrote the above equation in 3 equivalent ways:

$(cd-be)^2+(af)^2=2af(cd+be)$

$(af-be)^2+(cd)^2=2cd(af+be)$

$(cd-af)^2+(be)^2=2be(cd+af)$

Since the L.H.S. of the three equations is non-negative, we have

$(af)(cd+be)\geq 0$

$(cd)(af+be)\geq 0$

$(be)(af+cd)\geq 0$

I'm stuck from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrong.

Taking dfeuer's $x=af,y=be,z=cd$ we have an indefinite ternary quadratic form
$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 2 y z - 2 z x - 2 x y.$$ It has a nontrivial null cone. In particular, take
$$  x = 1 - \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}, \; \;   y = 1 + \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}, \; \; z = 1. $$

Since $$ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 2 y z - 2 z x - 2 x y = (y-x)^2 - 2 z(x+y) + z^2,  $$
and $$ y-x = \sqrt 3, \; x+y = 2, z = 1, $$
we get
$$ 3 - 2 \cdot 2 + 1 = 3 - 4 + 1 = 0.  $$

So, take, 
$$ d=e=f=1, \; \; a = 1 - \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}, \; \;   b = 1 + \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}, \; \; c = 1. $$

10:55 Pacific. Here is an integer one $x=1, y=1, z=4,$ so
$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 2 y z - 2 z x - 2 x y = 1 + 1 + 16 - 8 - 8 - 2 = 0.$$

11:55 Pacific. Apparently all  integer solutions follow the same pattern. Since the thing is homogeneous, you can multiply any solution by an integer, positive or negative or whatever. Given that, all **primitive integer** solutions with $x > 0$ and in order are $$  x = t^2, \; \; y = u^2, \; \;  z = (t+u)^2,  $$ for positive integers $t,u.$ Going back to the original variables, we get
$$ a=t, \; \; b=u, \; \; c=d= t+u, \; \; e=u, \; \;  f = t.  $$ Who Knew?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is note that certain variables always appear together. Rearranging the factors just a drop gives
$$(cd)^2-2(be)(cd)+(be)^2-2(af)(cd)+(af)^2-2(af)(be),$$
so the equation is *really* in variables $cd$, $be$, and $af$. That should make things a bit easier to handle.

Comment: ... and the solution set obviously contains the lines $(af,cd,be)=(0,t,t)$, $(t,t,0)$ and $(t,0,t)$, _and_ these lines are the only solutions with one of the coordinates zero. Since the equation is homogenous, the solution set is a conic in the projective plane, which cannot possibly consist of three isolated points, so the desired conclusion is _false_.